Installing HP proliant ML310r server gen8 fails
I would like to ask for some help please.
I am not pro, but rather enthusiast.
I bought my first "home" server HP proliant ml310e gen 8 server. It has ILO problem (fault chip) thus network diagnostic is a problem.
Bios version from 2013, not able to update due to HP policy to have for each server some kind of service contract.
I check memories (16 Gb) and disks (badblocks). All PASS, 0 errors.
The problem is, that starting from installing proxmox VE, ubuntu, debian or Almalinux, everything fails during the install.
I am currently stuck, not able to install everything. I dont have access to any logs (dont know, how to access them, as the installation goes from USB stick) and no particular error to follow and analyse. From what I could noticed the problem is some kind of writeable error, but both memory and disks looks fine.
Currently there no raid config in place, only one 1TB (raid 0) disk installed in slot 1 to make it easier and exclude possible errors caused by bad raid config as well.
To give you hint of what I am trying to build. The goal of mine is to run few docker images. Some Immich, home assistant, CCTV sel hosted with google Coral (like Frigate), next cloud or simmilar for files. Originally I though to have proxmox, but native docker would probably fit good as well without the virtualization overhead.
Anyway, thank you for your energy to help me to solve my issues.
Example of some errors in images: enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
